# How do I format my date with NSDateFormat?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to format my date. I have this code:

```
func recuperaData() -> String? {

 let data = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .ShortStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle)
    return "\(data)"
}
```

This code returns me a string like this:

> Apr 13, 2016, 10:50 AM instead I want 13/04/2016, 10:50

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Use [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/)

```
func recuperaData() -> String?
{
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm"
    let selecteddate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
    return selecteddate
}
```